# Handling Big Data with OSB Proxy

Tags: oracle, soa, osb, oracle-fusion-middleware, bigdata

I have created a OSB Proxy Service(Messaging Service) which loading the data with a MFL file.

The format of data is:

```
1/1/2007;00:11:00;2.500;0.000;242.880;10.200;0.000;0.000;0.000;
1/1/2007;00:12:00;2.494;0.000;242.570;10.200;0.000;0.000;0.000;
```

All the data records are : 2075259

The total size of file(.txt or .data) is : 130MB.

Which is best way to handling all these data in order to inserted to an OSB Proxy and transformed all the data in a simple xml file?

I have tested with a small size of records(5000) and it works as expected but how i should insert all this data in the proxy?

The MFL transformation is a valid idea or i should create a FileAdapter Proxy which will received the data from a dbtable?

Please for your suggestion

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could use a claim check pattern: http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/StoreInLibrary.html

Comment: My main problem is that i want to get all the data at once, and transformed it to an xml, without any pattern. Just to pass all the data to one xml format.Will be in a group list. Each line data to a part of a group xml list.

Answer (score 2):

ESBs are efficient at handling messages in the order of KBs, not MBs, although this is very subjective and depends a lot on the number of concurrent requests, transactions per second, sizing of hardware etcetera. As Trent points out in a comment, you could implement a [claim check pattern](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/StoreInLibrary.html) and delegate the file transformation to an external utility, such as perl or similar.